# How do you paraphrase “If any more disconnect was needed?”

Tags: meaning, grammar

The following is an excerpt from the *Bloomberg news* of June 21. I have difficulty understanding the first part.

> ***If any more disconnect was needed,*** the Group of Seven nations took the extraordinary step last weekend of standing by Japan’s
> unpopular Prime Minister Yoshihide Suga and adding to its communique
> that we “reiterate our support for the holding of the Olympic and
> Paralympic Games Tokyo 2020.”

Answer (score 1):

You should have quoted the preceding paragraph, to understand to what part your phrase is referring to.

> The pandemic makes this an extraordinary era, but even so, Japan has
> only limited power over a risky event on its own soil because Tokyo
> faces massive financial penalties from the IOC should it unilaterally
> call off the event. The widespread opposition of Japanese people to
> continuing with the games — already postponed since last year — has
> made plowing ahead with them feel out of touch.
>
> ***If any more disconnect was needed***, the Group of Seven nations took the extraordinary step last weekend of standing by Japan’s
> unpopular Prime Minister Yoshihide Suga and adding to its communique
> that we “reiterate our support for the holding of the Olympic and
> Paralympic Games Tokyo 2020.” ([source](https://www.japantimes.co.jp/opinion/2021/06/21/commentary/japan-commentary/olympics-about-doctors-not-athletes/))

The article speaks about *disruptions* caused by the pandemic in the organisation of the Olympic Games in Japan and *oppositions* between the Olympic Games planning and the Japanese public. And then it adds ***yet another disruption*** by starting the new paragraph with ***If any more disconnect was needed,*** meaning:

> ***As if this were not enough/ If it was not bad enough/ If there was not enough dissension (disconnect)***

***Disconnect*** is [increasingly](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=disconnect_VERB%2Cdisconnect_NOUN&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdisconnect_VERB%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdisconnect_NOUN%3B%2Cc0) used as a noun, it seems, and it is often used to express a clash between two groups of people:

> Disconnect [noun]: a lack of connection; a failure of two things to relate:
>
> - There’s a ***disconnect** between the public and the media*. ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/disconnect))

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I understand there is a disconnect ... But I still don't understand what the writer means by saying in a conditional phrase, "If any more disconnect was needed." I think the G7 nations confirmed their support for the holding of the Tokyo Olympics and Paralympics because they didn't want any more disconnect. Maybe I'm confused about the usage of "if" in this context. Could you please elaborate on it?

Comment: On the contrary, the G7 nations added more disconnect by supporting the holding of the Tokyo Olympics. That's not what the Japanese people want.

Comment: Consider: **At the best of times this makes running a business challenging; in a post COVID/Brexit world, this is mentally and financially crippling for many. _If this was not enough,_ let us consider the impact of rising patient charges.** So this expression is used to add a bad thing to another one/to a series of other bad things OR to add a good thing to another one/to a series of other good things.

Answer (score 0):

You could say disagreement or lack of shared agenda instead of disconnect, in this case presumably between the leadership of the G7 nations and the real world. It's not surprising this comes from a US media group: disconnect is not really a noun, but verbs are often co-opted as nouns in US English, and vice versa, as evidenced by evidence!